# Plotting a GPS trail route on a Google map, embedding to site

Tags: android, google-maps

*New to Stackoverflow, did some searching and couldn't find anything that really matched what I'm looking for unless I'm using the wrong keywords. I did find guides on how to plot a route when you know the actual route, but I'm looking to do it from actually walking it, see below:*

I'm fairly new to web development and am looking to plot maps of a trail on a website using an embedded Google map or some other free map platform if it's suitable (OSM?) I have an Android phone and I'd like to actually be able to:
(1) walk this route, 
(2) take the GPS data somehow & 
(3) match it up to a Google map to 
(4) post it on my webpage.

That will help visitors know the actual route (which is not available on Google Maps in any detail) and have somewhat of a "guide" of the near-exact trail route. I imagine this can be done, as Runkeeper and other applications do this (with additional data on speed, time, etc.) for tracking your runs. I don't really want any of that additional data as much as I would like to just capture the GPS route itself, and have it in some format that I can then use to make a map out of automatically. Not sure where to start with this, or if it can be done easily. Any information or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I have no experience in Java; very limited Javascript and OK in HTML/CSS. I've never used the Google Maps API either.

Thanks!

Comment: Two years later...can you now answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [API Picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) lists to help you on the most common things you may want to do on a map or with location-based data, and this also suggests the API that most suits your needs.

Listed below are the useful APIs to plot a route on a map:

- Polylines in the Google Maps Android API
- Polylines in the Google Maps SDK for iOS
- Polylines in the Google Maps JavaScript API
- Directions mode in the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)
- Paths in the Google Static Maps API (a web service)

Links of useful APIs for whatever you want to do on a map can be found in the documentation.